# EBADF while extracting zip

Tags: android, zip, extract, android-5.0-lollipop

When I extract a zip file to a folder on external storage, it works on Android OS 7, but on Android OS 5 it raises exception after a few files:

```
java.io.IOException: write failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
```

What is it? I have gave all permissions and the strange point is it extracts a few files and then crashes!